# how to display all records of table in formview control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Table
Rollno       Name
101          XYZ
102          ABC

With the following code i m only able to display the first row of the table
That is
101          XYZ

rollno:
                '>
                name:
                '>

how to display the next row of the table

102          ABC

I am using this to bind to formview.

```
<ItemTemplate> rollno: <asp:Label ID="itemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rollno") %>'></asp:Label><br /> name: <asp:Label ID="imageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                rollno:
                <asp:Label ID="itemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rollno") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                name:
                <asp:Label ID="imageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: How to bind next row values to the Bind function

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `ItemTemplate` to make next row in new line.

```
<ItemTemplate> 
   <div> 
     rollno: <asp:Label ID="itemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rollno") %>'></asp:Label>
     name: <asp:Label ID="imageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'> </asp:Label>
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

To get next row, you need to bind an IEnumerable type of datasource to FormView , like

- Get a result in List of objects bind to FormView
- Get result as DataTable ( make sure you have multiple rows) and bind that to `FormView`